# Eager loading of derived class in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, eager-loading

I have a model like this:

```
public abstract class Point
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name_F { set; get; }
    public byte Side { set; get; }
}

public class Place : Point
{
    public bool IsATM { set; get; }
    public bool Is24h { set; get; }
    public string Tel { set; get; }
    public virtual Category Category { set; get; }
}

public class Street : Point
{
    public bool IsWalkway { set; get; }
}
```

I want to load all of the Point table records including records for Place and Street which are derived from Point class.

I used this but I didn't get any data:

```
var points = Context.Points
                     .OfType<Place>()
                     .Include(p => p.SubCategory)
                     .Concat<Points>(Context.Points.OfType<Street>());
```

I would like to get Places and Streets in the same query.

Any idea?

Comment: This can't even run. `Points.OfType<Place>()` is implicitly cast to `IQueryable<Point>`, so the navigation property `SubCategory` is not recognized. You have to get the data in two separeate queries.

Comment: @GertArnold It runs. I've checked it but when I add Concat term it retrieves nothing.